# Bundle install specific nokogiri -v '1.6.1' issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I accidentally deleted some libraries (I think, don't ask how).  Now I can't install the nokogiri version I need.  I have read the other posts with similar problems and their solutions aren't helping.  Please see the following errors :(

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /private/var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/bundler20161219-83285-1fnegt2nokogiri-1.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161219-83285-voqu1e.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /private/var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/bundler20161219-83285-1fnegt2nokogiri-1.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /private/var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/bundler20161219-83285-1fnegt2nokogiri-1.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
```

Then some config options

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/bundler20161219-83285-1fnegt2nokogiri-1.6.1/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/bundler20161219-83285-1fnegt2nokogiri-1.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/bundler20161219-83285-1fnegt2nokogiri-1.6.1/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried brew installing libxml2, tried installing with libraries, etc.  What in the world could this be??

Comment: Getting nokogiri and its dependancies to work can get tedious. For starters, tell us your OS to help you find the library

Comment: For example in my Mac with el Capitan I had to do `brew install libxml2 libxslt`to install the system libraries, then, using bundler, `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2` For more info take a look at http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.2.1 -- --use-system-libraries
```

Comment: Right, I had tried installing with system libraries... However, I answered this questions with my own solution.   I really just messed up my libraries... So there were no "system libraries" to use.  I think. :/

Comment: If you got the answer please share, this will helpful for other

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed RVM which installed a lot of the missing libraries.